# PHP Batch Processing For Loop

Tags: php, for-loop, get, batch-processing, nested-loops

I have an end point that I can send a GET request to and it returns a different result depending on the limit and offset.

```
https://example-foo-bar.com?l=100&o=0 // returns the first 100 items.
```

I want to create a for loop (or a Nested for loop I assume) that returns a 100 items at a time, adding the result to an array each time, until the end of the response. I have the code for sending the curl request and storing the result, just struggling on the batch processing part.

Something like:

```
https://example-foo-bar.com?l=100&o=0

https://example-foo-bar.com?l=100&o=99

https://example-foo-bar.com?l=100&o=199

https://example-foo-bar.com?l=100&o=218 // end of response ?
```

I also know how many result there are in total, stored as $count;

---

I ended up with something like this but it doesn't feel like the best practice:

```
function testLoop(){

  $limit = 100;

  $count = getCount();

  $j = ceil($count/$limit);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
    $offset = $i*100;
    echo 'https://example-foo-bar?l='.$limit.'&o='.$offset.'';
  }
 }

 testLoop();
```

Comment: _“until the end of the file”_ - what file?

Comment: End of response even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. But are you looking for something like that?

```
$offset = 0;
$limit = 100;
$run = true;
$result_array = array();
while($run) {      
  $result_array = array_merge($result_array, json_decode(file_get_contents("https://example-foo-bar.com?l=".$limit."&o=".$offset),true));
  $offset = $offset + $limit;
  if($offset == {somenumber}) {
    $run = false;
  }
}
```

Then use a cron job to call the php file

Comment: Result is a Json object

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check if that does what you want.

Comment: If you are happy, please markl it as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create table 'schedule' and store the data id, link_name,offset and status column
2. set cron to execute every 10 minutes  and take First  an entry (one) which status =0
3. pass param to testLoop($limit) to call function. It may entire link of only offset =0, offset =99, offset =199 like that
4. After completed to update status=1 in  schedule table.
5. After 10 minute cron Call Step1.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use  Cron for such type of batch process you can also use php-resque